# How to calculate $P(A|B,C)$ from Bayesian Network?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

Say I have a bayesian network B <- A -> C. I need to calculate $P(A|B,C)$. How can I do that?
I tried doing:

$P(A|B,C)=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)}$

I also tried various other combinations of formulae (I've been at this so long I've forgotten almost all of them and my calculations book is a mess). All of them lead up to requiring $P(B,C)$ which I have no idea how to obtain. I'm relatively new to this. Where should I go from here?

Comment: Nevermind, I found another similar question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112566/how-to-compute-this-conditional-probability-in-bayesian-networks
More complicated example, but it answered my question